# Google Analytics code (analytics.js) not reporting anything

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, analytics, analytics.js

The site is http://www.juicysatsuma.com/ and I'm certain the Tracking ID is correct.

There are no errors in the network log or the console. I can see Google being pinged when I refresh the page, and when I interact with the site (I have a couple of events set up). GA reports show not page hits, no events, and nobody on the site. The tracking ID statis under GA properties is 'Tracking Not Installed'.

It's the first time I've used GA since they moved from ga.js to analytics.js. I never had this problem before, but I'm not ready to move back to old code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed your analytics (within the last 24 hours), then it may take at least 24 hours for you to see data in your standard reports. Have you tried checking in your real-time reports for your simultaneous visits? If you see data there, then your tracking is correctly installed and you only need to wait at least 24 hours, during which time you can ignore the "Tracking not installed" message. Your tracking code looks fine, and I can see pageview hits and event hits when I load the page.